# Guest login support in lightdm webkit greeter

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, guest-session, webkit

I'm having trouble getting the guest login option to work in the Webkit LightDM greeter, which is a shame as it's otherwise a superb tool for developing custom greeters.

Looking through the source on both LightDM and the Webkit greeter it seems that this feature might not be implemented, but I'm no expert. Has anyone else tried this?